# Movement/rotation etc. hypersensitive in perspective view but normal in orthographics

Tags: 3d-view, orthographic

I have been mostly using blender in orthographic mode but sometimes I use perspective view. My problem is that in perspective view the tools use is sometimes hyper sensitive. For example if I want to move a vertice. Even with shift the selection just moves so fast they just zap across the screen. Sometimes it could even be super slow. It is not a scale issue with my objects. I'm thinking this is because of some blender setting but why is perspective so unpredictable while ortho is perfectly fine?

Comment: Please clarify you question with an image. Please show your Blender work in screen shot for this and all future questions.

Comment: Maybe the view pivot point is unfavourably placed. Try Viewing Selected after selecting a vertex with the NumpadEnter key.

Comment: Pivot point is very far away from the object. It is a large landscape (highway scene) so the pivot is at 0,0,0 but the object mesh is like a kilometer away. Why would it use the pivot point anyways??? It is very unpredictable so I can not make a blend. In some cases in perspective view the tools are just incredibly sensitive.

Comment: Pivot can not be very far away from the object, it is setting available to be changed. Origin point can be far away instead and if in Edit mode it is used as pivot then chances are 3d cursor is used as pivot. Try to change Pivot point to something like Median point

Answer (score 1):

- Create 2 3D View windows.  Creating many windows in Blender is Easy.

  - One in Orthogonal View.
  - Perspective View
- Perform the operation in Orthogonal,  while viewing in Perspective.  Also start your change with the mouse reasonably far away from the item in question to dampen the operation.  For example for small angles start with the mouse far away from the object.
- Also other tools exist beyond Grab.  Try the Snap operation.

Comment: Two separate windows is not an option. I just press 5 to switch. I don't want to tho. And it is not just the grab tool. Many other tools are affected as well. Why is the perspective like this?

Comment: With my current   of well .... whatever ... and the sands of time ⏳ in movement your option must be the best.  Good luck.  I wish I knew your secret.  I am sure its quite experienced.